# Generic Noether position

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If we generate $m$ random polynomials $f_1$, $f_2$,..., $f_m$ of degree $d$ (with $d$ given) in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$, can we have in general that $V = V(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m)$ is in Noether position with respect to $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_r$, here $r$ should be the dimension of $V$.

From the proof of Noether normalization theorem, we know that by a random linear change of variables, we can get a variety in Noether position. Is there any similar result for random polynomials' case?